# Magento2 - How to remove certain States from list at Checkout or registration?

Tags: magento2, checkout, register

the list of region with depend country, i want to remove certain state from everywhere in site..

like I want to remove -  Alaska, Hawaii, American Samoa, Guam, Marshall Islands.

How we can achieve this?

Comment: This will help you - https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-restrict-specific-us-states-in-checkout-magento-2/ To restrict some US States in the checkout. For this, They have created a US State restriction selection drop-down in the admin panel system configuration. In the example

Comment: Hello @AnasMansuri if solution solves your query then mark as accepted which will help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

> like I want to remove - Alaska, Hawaii, American Samoa, Guam, Marshall
>   Islands.

**[This](https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-restrict-specific-us-states-in-checkout-magento-2/)** will help you.

> To restrict some US States in the checkout. For this, They have
>   created a US State restriction selection drop-down in the admin panel
>   system configuration. In the example

And Then You can select the US States from the Allowed US States in Checkout drop-down which you will want to display in the checkout form.

[image]

Comment: this feature apply only for checkout page right !!!